# what does this warning mean (MSDN docs regarding modifying data and the DataTable.RowChanged event)?

Tags: c#, events, dataset

On MSDN [Handling DataTable Events (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx) it reads:

Caution 
Data corruption can occur if data is modified in a DataSet from which the RowChanged event is raised. No exception will be raised if such data corruption occurs.

I can't seem to understand what this is saying.

Thanks.

Comment: Since DataSet has multiple status rows (Original vs Current) - this relates to if you are changing something on RowChanged event, the DataSet may not be able to keep the status due to race condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a aloud**

Check if `e.Row["ColumnName"]=<Some Value>` can be done. If so then may be it is talking about that.